# SQL Query to Return Unique Dates based on another Datetime column for the current date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table (well the below is a scaled down example):

```
CID | LogDate       | RemDate  
1   | 2015-05-06    | 2015-10-01  
2   | 2015-05-06    | 2015-10-01  
2   | 2015-05-06    | 2015-10-30  
1   | 2015-01-03    | 2015-10-01  
1   | 2015-01-03    | 2015-10-01  
2   | 2015-04-06    | 2015-10-01  
2   | 2014-04-06    | 2015-10-01  
3   | 2015-05-06    | 2015-12-01
```

I need to return only rows that have a unique [remdate] on the current date & ignore the others even when they have a matching [CID]....

I'd expect to have back the two unique remdates (`2015-12-01` & `2015-10-30`)

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here, any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With your sample data, what are the desired results?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that! Basically, I'd expect to have back the two unique remdates (2015-12-01 & 2015-10-30)

Comment: Seems like he wants no duplicated remdates in his query.

Comment: I think he might be after any date with only a single entry on today's date.  Need more clarification.

Comment: Yes KingOfAllTrades, that's what I'm after! Sorry to all for not being able to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to return those remdates that appear once in the table, you can use aggregation for that with `count`:

```
select remdate
from yourtable
group by remdate
having count(remdate) = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cae26/3)

If you want to return those remdates that appear once per `logdate`, just add that field to your `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to remove duplicates then use DISTINCT.

```
SELECT distinct remdate, * FROM table
```

Comment: saying `distinct remdate, *` will not give you only distinct remdates (because of the `*`).. rather it will look across the whole row and make sure you have unique rows.  Mysql has an option that produces something similar, but sql server does not.

Comment: No sorry, my fault for not explaining, only if the remdate hasn't previously been added on another logdate, I want those to be ignored totally on the return.